# CSS Styling For Image Overlay that give a feeling of a glass

Tags: css

Would you know how in css to create the effect that you can see on the below screenshot, where an image is looking as if it's behind a glass. On the left there is a white glow? And on the right top side, I think the border is giving a feeling like the image is "inside".

[image]

How would you recreate the same feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be hard to perfectly interpret the glow effect on the left edge.

Anyway one strategy to get close could be to apply the following layers:

- `.shadow` - casting a shadow ***inside*** with `box-shadow: var(--box-shadow) inset`
- `.glow` - a fixed length vertical stripe with `backdrop-filter: blur(1px)`
- `.opacity` - an overlay with background: `linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)`
- `.scatter` - adds a picture (with transparency supported) above the glass reflection (I chose a bad example in the demo so I preferred to keep it disabled)
- `.blur` - blurs the whole glass reflection with a linear gradient

I later added a set of options on top to toggle on and off the above said features that behind the curtains is just setting/unsetting the corresponding css class to the `.frame` element.

The feature ***scattering*** adds a background picture in the glowing container that will repeat a background pattern having transparency. I chose a very low resolution picture here and the result is ***gruesome***. Anyway I'm confident if you can craft a better picture it will look much better while keeping the same exact css strategy.

```js
const frame = document.getElementById('frame');

document.querySelectorAll('fieldset input[type=checkbox]')
  .forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
      if( event.target.checked )
        frame.classList.add(event.target.dataset.class);
      else
        frame.classList.remove(event.target.dataset.class);
    });
  });
```

```css
#frame{
  --bezel: 6px;
  --box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  --img-url: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/08/27/14/19/mountains-55067_1280.png");
  --border-radius: 10px;
  --bezel-color: white;
  --glass-blur-width: 15%;
}

body{
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.controls{
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.controls ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.controls label{
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.controls input{
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*styles the parent .frame*/
.frame {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  background: var(--bezel-color);
}

/*styles the picture element inside the .frame*/
.frame .img {  
  width: calc(100% - var(--bezel) * 2);
  height: calc(100% - var(--bezel) * 2);
  margin: var(--bezel);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);  
  background-image: var(--img-url);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*layer for opacity*/
.img:before,
/*layer for glass reflection*/
.img:after
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--bezel);
  left: var(--bezel);
  height: calc(100% - var(--bezel) * 2);
}

/*layer of lowered opacity with a linear gradient*/
.frame.opacity .img::before{
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7));
  width: calc(100% - var(--bezel) * 2);
}

/*casts a shadow inside(!)*/
.frame.shadow .img{
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow) inset;
}

/*layer adding a left vertical stripe with blur*/
.frame.glowing .img::after{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
  width: var(--glass-blur-width);
  border-top-left-radius: var(--border-radius);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

/*adds a mask to the glass glow, with a background picture*/
.frame.scatter .img::after{
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/fYZJ3KR/scattered-pattern4.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

/*blurs the glass glow*/
.frame.blur .img::after{
  filter: url('#glass-filter');
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="controls">
  <legend>Show/Hide features:</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opacity" data-class="opacity" checked>
      <label>gradient opacity</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="glowing" data-class="glowing" checked>
      <label>glowing</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="shadow"  data-class="shadow" checked>
      <label>shadow</label>   
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="scatter"  data-class="scatter" >
      <label>scatter</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="blur"  data-class="blur" checked>
      <label>linear blur</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<div id="frame" class="frame opacity glowing shadow blur">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>

<svg height="0">
<defs>
  <filter id="glass-filter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
  </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: wow! Nice one! Definitely great approach. It gives you a similar feel when you look at the edges. 

Thanks for that! 

Will just need to find a solution for the glow effect. Maybe it should be just another image on top?

Comment: I went the extra mile and added the blur gradient filter over the glass reflection. Now I think there are all the parts to compose the best result. If a better picture gets chosen for the `.scatter` class it will be the top. I did my best

Comment: Hey Diego. Amazing! You did go the extra mile - thank you for that! Love the result! Wish you all the best.